# Python logging custom handler and formatter nothing gets logged

Tags: python, logging

Hi I am trying to enable logs on python and for some reason nothing gets logged. Can some one help me what mistake I am making.

```
def setup():
    logger = logging.getLogger('mytest')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')

    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler('mylog.log')
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
    logger.debug('hello world')
```

Comment: you need the call `setLevel` on the `logger` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example will make it a bit more clear. The main level you need to set is for the `logger` object. You can check the `logger` level by calling the [getEffectiveLevel](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel) method.

```
def setup():
    logger = logging.getLogger('mytest')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler('mylog.log')
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

    logger.critical("before setting Level on logger, effective level = {}".format(
            logger.getEffectiveLevel()))


    #THIS WON'T BE logged becuse logger level is WARN
    # and DEBUG < WARN
    logger.debug('logging debug before setting debug level')

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logger.critical("after setting Level on logger, effective level = {}".format(
            logger.getEffectiveLevel()))


    #THIS WILL BE logged in mylog.log because DEBUG >= DEBUG
    logger.debug('logging debug after setting debug level')

    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)


    #THIS WON'T BE logged in mylog.log because fileHandler level is CRITICAL--->
    # and DEBUG < CRITICAL
    logger.debug("this won't be printed in mylog.log")


    #THIS WILL BE logged in mylog.log BECAUSE CRITICAL >= CRITICAL--->
    logger.critical("logging at critical level")
```